# How to Sign out of getstream.io feed client

Tags: getstream-io

I need to know how to sign out of get-stream feed client. or change the token.
here is my configuration

`Client.config = .init(apiKey: "key",appId: "aped",token: str)`

Comment: please provide some more information about what you are trying to do (ie. include the programming language)

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of the Stream Feeds SDK v.2.2.0 or higher.

```
// Setup a shared Stream Client.
Client.config = .init(apiKey: "<#ApiKey#>", appId: "<#AppId#>")

// Setup a Stream user, when your user was logged in.
Client.shared.setupUser(token: token) { _ in 
    // Do all your requests from here. Reload feeds and etc.
}
```

You can find more examples on wiki pages here:
https://github.com/GetStream/stream-swift/wiki

Comment: In this case when I try to post something new using the TextToolBar I keep getting a The current user not found error

Comment: You have to setup the Stream client and user when the user logged in. Can you show the code you use to setup the Stream client and user?

Comment: Im not sure how to set up the stream client and user. I am using swift and followed the tutorial

Comment: To sign out, you need to create a new instance of the Client with a new token and create a new Stream user for the logged-in user as described in the answer.

Comment: I did all of that and it keeps me logged in as the old user

Comment: I understand that I can use a non shared instance of client but in that case how do I use the native iOS text toolbar in order to create new post? and the comments pages also seems to use the shared instance which I cannot change

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment. A new version in development and it will be released in 1 or 2 days. It will have changes to use the shared as a single solution. The user autorization will be improved. I'll let you know.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the fix! I saw that there was an update to the GitHub repo. How would I go about implementing It.